# Routing in angular 2 using plain javascript?

Tags: angular

Routing in angular 2 using plain javascript ?
I want to do routing using angular 2 without using typescript

Comment: Why would you want to do this in plain js when you can do it in typescript so easily?

Comment: You should use the [Angular Router](https://angular.io/guide/router)